# create-react-app - How to bundle JS files

Tags: reactjs

I created a React app using **create-react-app**.
If I run `npm run build`, create-react-app generates 3 different JS files inside the **build/static/js** folder.

But for the purpose of this specific app, I need to bundle all those 3 JS files in a single file.

Is it something, which I can achieve with create-react-app? 
If not what would be the best way to bundle those 3 JS files to a single file?

Comment: Maybe you can try this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407

Answer (score 9):

You can build your own webpack.config.js at the root of your project, something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

Then you can adapt the script to build in the package.json:

```
"build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle",
"build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 5 Update:

I attempted rrd answer above and ran into an error trying to install `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` as I am using Webpack 5 which appears to [not work past Webpack 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298689/uglifyjs-and-webpack-v5) and instead to use the `terser-webpack-plugin` which comes with Webpack 5. Below is the modified `webpack.config.js` to make this work with Webpack 5.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path")
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
}
```

modified build scripts in **package.json**

```
"build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle",
"build:react": "react-scripts build",
"build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
```

devDependencies in **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
  "glob": "^8.0.3",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
  "webpack": "^5.72.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
}
```

Comment: How would you attach this bundle with HTML element if I want to display this react app in a HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Try webpack to customise build, minimize and lot more features are available

Please fallow this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack,
docs: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/