# UglifyJS and webpack v5

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, uglifyjs, terser

We've been using UglifyJS and webpack v4 for our react code, but then just updated to webpack v5. It appears that UglifyJS does not work with webpack v5. Is there an alternative? We need something that works with babel-loader.

Thanks

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/
You don't have to install Uglify plugin, it has inbild support in webpack 5

Answer (score 29):

Webpack 5 comes with [`terser-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) out of the box, hence you can just `import` it and configure as you wish.

Comment: I want to remove all the consoles from bundle.will it do automatically?

Answer (score 17):

As Sam said, Webpack 5 comes with the Terser plugin which does what UglifyJS used to do. Here's an example on how to use the Terser plugin for webpack.

```js
// webpack.config.js
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    ...
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin(),
        ],
    }
};
```